# Different way to add label to message beside using modify or a restricted scope with gmail api

Tags: php, google-apps-script, label, gmail-api

Below is how i am currently adding a label to a message with the gmail api. this method works but it requires the modify scope which is restricted and requires verification and issue is well we only using this scope to add labels to messages and not utilising the full scope and may not pass verification based on that. any way doing it another way without a restricted scope.

```
function modifyMessage($messageId, $lid) {
      $labels = [];
      array_push($labels, $lid);
      $mods = $this->modifyService;
      $mods->setAddLabelIds($labels);

      try {
        $message = $this->service->users_messages->modify('me', $messageId, $mods);

        return "label added";
      } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
      }
    }//modifyMessage
```

i did try adding it to the message on the send but this seemed to add the label but as soon as the message was sent it was taken off the email. below is my example of doing this,

```
       $mail->preSend();

       $mime = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
       $m = $this->msgService;
       $data = base64_encode($mime);
       $data = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''),$data); // url safe
       $m->setRaw($data);
       $m->getId();
       $messageId =  $m->getId();
       $lid = $this->manageUserLabel($var);

       $labels = [];
       array_push($labels, $lid);
       $m->setLabelIds($labels); 

       $this->service->users_messages->send('me', $m);
```

this seems to attach the label correctly but as soon as it is sent the label is removed.

any ideas ?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/create#auth), you have the choice of using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels` scope to create labels, so try using that with your script instead, but I don't think you can remove the authorization screen for the user.

Comment: i have already created the label, i am trying to attach the label to a message been sent without having to use the modify scope or if possible not a restricted scope.

Comment: My bad, I had misunderstood, you can't assign a label to another user's inbox, if you add the label to a message and then send it, the other user will receive it without label, they have to set it up themselves. You can only create labels in your own mail, or if you have GSuite and you are the admin, the other peoples' in the domain

Answer (score 0):

Posting for documentation purposes.

You can't assign a label to another user's inbox, if you add the label to a message and then send it, the other user will receive it without label, they have to set it up themselves. You can only create labels in your own mail, or if you have GSuite and you are the admin, the other peoples' in the domain.